# Rename folder name in Fedora

Tags: fedora, rename

I am using `rename` in Fedora 31 to rename some bulk of folders. Essentially, I want to remove all the spaces from the folder and replace it with dots. I am using following command

```
rename -v " " "." *
```

However, above command only replaces first occurrence of space. For example, to shows me following message

```
'folder with multiple space' -> 'folder.with multiple space'
```

If I run it again, it will just replace next space. Is there way to replace all at once? Debian/Ubuntu version has `sed` type command `"s/ /\./g"` which didn't work in my case. It gives me error that not enough arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using `zsh`, use [`zmv`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/zshcontrib.1.en#Styles_2)

For bash:

```
for i in *\ *; do
    mv -vnT "$i" "${i// /.}"
done
```

Comment: `zmv ` actually worked. I used `zmv '* *' '$f:gs/ /.'`

Answer (score 1):

The man page says that's how it works, it replaces only the first match and no option to overwrite that.

man rename:

```
rename  will  rename the specified files by replacing the first
occurrence of expression in their name by replacement.
```

Of course you can script it around:

```
while [ "$(rename -v " " "." *)" ]
do
  true
done
```

Debian/Ubuntu uses a totally different `rename`.

Comment: I used `zmv` finally which was one-liner and easier :)